# How to Parameterize Year Month Day [YYYYMMDD] with file created datetime [YYYYMMDDHHMMSS] in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

The following Azure Data Factory parameter will pull in the tablename from an Azure SQLDB

```
@pipeline().parameters.TableName
```

Can someone show me how to add the above parameter to include [YYYYMMDD] and file created datetime  [YYYYMMDDHHMMSS]

The output should look like 'mytable_20230529_20230529103096'

I tried adding the year as follows:

```
@pipeline().parameters.TableName.dayOfYear()
```

But I got the error:

```
Position 33 'TableName' is a primitive and doesn't support nested properties
```

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think I need to somehow append the date as follows ```Append Date to a filename: @concat('Test_', formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy-dd-MM'))```. But I'm not sure how to append it to an exsiting parameter ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use concat to concatanate strings, and formatDateTime to format the date to the way you need it:

```
@concat(
    pipeline().parameters.TableName,
    '_',
    formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyyMMdd'),
    '_',
    formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyyMMddhhmmss')
    )
```

Results:

[image: output]

Comment: Hi @ChenHirsh, I've just read that file extension are ignored when file name is configured in the output dataset. The extension will be used as the sink file name and the file extension setting will be ignore. Therefore, my output filename is as follows: tablename_20230530_20230530034722 . Is there anyway I could add .csv to the file?

Comment: @Patterson, just add it to the concat command: @concat(
    pipeline().parameters.TableName,
    '_',
    formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyyMMdd'),
    '_',
    formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyyMMddhhmmss'),
 '.csv'
    )